# Trying to style notification bar extension and the changes are not applying from styles.css

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, css

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/notification-bar.html

I have installed this extension and it says I should be able to style it with my own CSS.

[image]

Even when targeting #notification-bar in my styles.css and changing the background-color, the changes are not applying, even when using !important.

Why is this happening?

Comment: it seems the css is inlined, I wouldn't use module for this - I'll create static block and call it in header

Comment: Where could I find the css that is hardcoded into it so I can change it manually?

Comment: Try awesone notification bar extension with targeted  features
https://magecomp.com/magento-notification-bar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/notificationbar/html/styles.phtml`

[image]

I wouldn't use module for this - I'll create static block and call it in header

Comment: I went to this location and the folder didn't exist

Comment: how did you install this moudle

Comment: Just installed the normal way through magento connect

Comment: I did the same, it must be there, please logout of your ftp and login again

Comment: I am on cPanel I don't use FTP. This is so weird because I am in the exact same path and there is nothing underneath newsletter

Comment: refresh cpanel page